Dimension of a sum of vector spaces using the external direct sum
I am unsure of how to approach this question. I know how to go about it a different way, but the fact that I have to use the linear map to get the answer is what confuses me.
Let $ U, W \leq V $. Define a linear map $ T: U \oplus W \to V $, where $ U \oplus W $ is the external direct sum, defined by $ (u, w) \mapsto u + w $. Using this linear map, show that
$$
\dim(U + W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim(U \cap W).
$$

$U+W$ is the image of $T$. $U\cap W$ can be proved to be isomorphic to the kernel of $T$. $dim(U)+dim(W)$ is equal to the dimension of $U\oplus V$

Yes this makes total sense thank you.
